# Drop shadow for custom imageView

Tags: android, xml, android-imageview, shadow, layer-list

I have created a simple play icon. I imported the SVG file into Android Studio and sourced it as an imageView. However, unfortunately I was unable to bring over the drop down shadow from my Adope XD document. In either case I have been trying to replicate the drop down shadow effect via code. However I have been unsuccessful.

The image on the left is what I have, the image on the right is what I need:
[image]

I've been messing around with existing code with no success. Here is what I have so far:

imageView:

```html
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail_next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background_drop_shadow"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_next_button_image_select" />
```

ic_next_button_image_select (imported SVG):

```html
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="40dp"
    android:height="38dp"
    android:viewportWidth="40"
    android:viewportHeight="38">
  <path
      android:pathData="M12,0L28,0A12,12 0,0 1,40 12L40,26A12,12 0,0 1,28 38L12,38A12,12 0,0 1,0 26L0,12A12,12 0,0 1,12 0z"
      android:fillColor="#1ed760"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M27.6,17.28a2,2 0,0 1,-0 3.439l-10.083,5.987A2,2 0,0 1,14.5 24.987L14.5,13.013a2,2 0,0 1,3.021 -1.72Z"
      android:fillColor="#090909"/>
</vector>
```

background_drop_shadow (code I found and tried to work with):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Drop Shadow Stack -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <stroke android:color="#02000000" android:width="1dp"  />
            <corners android:radius="8dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <stroke android:color="#05000000" android:width="1dp" />
            <corners android:radius="7dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <stroke android:color="#10000000" android:width="1dp" />
            <corners android:radius="6dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <stroke android:color="#15000000" android:width="1dp" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <stroke android:color="#20000000" android:width="1dp" />
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <stroke android:color="#25000000" android:width="1dp" />
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <stroke android:color="#30000000" android:width="1dp" />
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Background -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve this you should use CardView. So it will be something like:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#687199"
    >

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="40dp"
        app:cardElevation="16dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/test"
            />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</FrameLayout>
```

[image: Example]

You just need to play around with `app:cardElevation` and `app:cardCornerRadius` to get the shadow you need.

Also, keep in mind that the Android shadow system draws darker and longer shadows when objects are closer to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I can't seem to achieve the exact effect I'm looking for using your method. Could you please adjust your code to possibly get that effect?

Comment: Great work! I realized that my problem was from else where, but its clear that your solution does work!